# How to Insert Date in a String format to Web form

Tags: java, selenium

I want to insert a date as a string like 23/8/1956 on a Web form. It should have the format: aug 23 1956 and the day , month, year is in a separate field.

I used the following function:

```
 public void dateInString() throws ParseException 
 {
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
     SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
     String dateString = "31-10-2013";
      try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(parser.format(date));
     } 
      catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     } 
 }
```

I received an error on the line : `Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);` It tells me that this is not a variable - why?
And after this function - how I can insert this to the Web ?

Comment: Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);

Comment: You called your variable `dateString` and then you're trying to use it as `dateInString`.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems

1. As [Lonely Neuron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826663/2664200) has already pointed out: your variable is called `NameString`, not `NameInString`
2. You need to get MMM dd YYYY(aug 23 1956) format as output

So change  `SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");` to `SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");`

**working code:**

```
public void  dateInString()  
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    String dateString = "31-10-2013";
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(parser.format(date));
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

**output:** Oct 31 2013

Comment: very observant for finding two bugs and not stopping after finding the first!

Comment: Thanks. But now, how can i insert every number to a certain filed? meaning, OCT to the month filed, 31 to the day filed and etc

Comment: @libi I could not undertand your problem

Comment: After i run this method i revived: oct 31 2013. Now i need to insert this date to a form in the web. I need to insert every data to a different filed. Like in a facebook make new user. In the birthday you have separate drop down for mouth / day / year.

Comment: @libi yes this correct. As I have already mentioned in my answer output. Also your expected output is also aug 23 1956

Answer (score 1):

With `dateInString` you are referencing a variable which doesn't exist. Change your declaration to:

```
String dateInString = "31-10-2013";
```

I would also suggest using a professional IDE like the (free) community version of [intelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/). That way you should be able to catch such errors easily for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Check this following code. I think it will get you desired output.

```
  public void dateInString() throws ParseException
  {
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
     SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
     String dateString = "31-10-2013";
     try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(parser.format(date));
     } 
     catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```